# Batik load SVG file in SVGGraphics2D

Tags: java, batik

I use batik for drawing svg, and save it. That work.

But now i try to load my svg file and add somthing.

I use this fonction for load my svg file

```
private static SVGDocument loadSVGDocument(String uri) {
    String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
    SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
    SVGDocument svgDocument = null;
    try {
        //svgDocument = factory.createSVGDocument(IMAGE_SVG);
        svgDocument = factory.createSVGDocument(uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return svgDocument;
}
```

and this for have SVGGraphics2D

```
SVGDocument svgDocument = loadSVGDocument(TEST_SVG);
SVGGraphics2D g = new SVGGraphics2D(svgDocument);
```

When i debug my SVGDocument have all children and attribut null
And when i generate image, is empty and size is 400x400

Where is problem when i load my SVG file?

Comment: Only a small hint: When you create an `SVGGraphics2D` with a document, then the document is the **target** for the painting operations. E.g. when you do something like `g.fillRect(10,10,20,30)`, then the document will contain a rectangle. But if the document already contains something, it will (probably) be overwritten. I don't know from the tip of my head how to use the `SVGGraphics` to **add** something to an **existing** document. It should be possible, but I would have to try it out.

Comment: Thx for your reply.

For this time i juste try to load on SVGGraphics2D and save it at jpg.
But my jpg is empty.
If i save in svg, is empty to.

Comment: You should try to clarify: 1. Do you want to load an SVG and save it as JPG? or 2. Do you want to load an SVG, add some custom elements (by painting into the `SVGGraphics`) and save the result as SVG?

Comment: point 2.
During my last test i see XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName(); return null;
It's normal ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not deeply familiar with batik (only used it once for https://github.com/javagl/SvgGraphics ). The main purpose of my comment was to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I every body
I find a solution for my case

I compare my generation and my file. First think i have svg root and one child g only.
svg root don t have with and height

I go search width and height

```
        Element elSVG = svgDocument.getRootElement();
    String width = elSVG.getAttribute("width");
    String height = elSVG.getAttribute("height");
```

and after root

```
NodeList nodes = elSVG.getElementsByTagName("g");
    Node node = nodes.item(0);
    Element el = null;
    if(Node.ELEMENT_NODE == node.getNodeType()) {
        el = (Element)node;
    }
```

and for the end add everything to graphics

```
        SVGGraphics2D g = new SVGGraphics2D(svgDocument);
    g.setTopLevelGroup(el);
    g.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(Integer.parseInt(width), Integer.parseInt(height)));
```

And that works for only one child to svg.
For me is OK for now.

And i try to add an other think like rectangle and that work to.